# Accessing/Modifying "Inspect element" elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know that the code when selecting "View page source" and "Inspect Element" can differ, to the point where document.getElementById will not work if referencing an element from "Inspect Element". I was wondering if there is a workaround to this.

Comment: please add your JS syntax(document.getElementById will not working) or page reference

Comment: Inspect element shows the webpage code live as it is with all modifications happening with javascript. View source shows you the html code received by the webserver to be interpreted by the web browser, the initial code. Therefore `document.getElementById` should work on an element you spotted in Inspect Element view. Can you provide an example of where you think it fails to work?

Comment: @AhsN say it correctly

Comment: View Source will just show you the raw HTML markup. Inspect Element provides a DOM inspector to visualise how the browser has interpreted that markup and store it in memory. It can change, but document.getElementById should still work fine if the element with the ID is visible in the inspector.